# How to get pagination to work with 2 wordpress loops

Tags: loop

I've got 2 separate loops on my blog page, and I'm unsure of how I can get both of them to work with pagination.

I've done a bit of Google research and the conclusion I've come to is that I need to combine both of these loops into one.  My question is how can I go about doing this?

My understanding of WordPress loops is fragile at the best of times, so a simple explanation would be thoroughly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="large-6 columns>
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'meta_key' => 'post_selection',
        'meta_value' => 'Article'
        );
        $article_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($article_query->have_posts()):
        while ($article_query->have_posts()) : $article_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <article class="blog">
         <!-- Content -->
        </article>
        <?php
   endwhile;
endif;
;?>
</div>
<div class="large-6 columns>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('post'),
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'meta_key' => 'post_selection',
            'meta_value' => 'Webinar'
        );
        $webinar_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($webinar_query->have_posts()):
            while ($webinar_query->have_posts()) : $webinar_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <article class="blog">
                    <!-- Content -->
                </article>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ;
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a big problem here and a pack of small problems.

The big one is — [pagination cannot be reliably changed within template](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/query-posts-breaks-pagination/). It just doesn't work like that. Pagination and main query are processed *before* template is ever reached.

So I would guess information you are coming upon is about the need to *properly adjust main query*, rather than "combine" loops.

The pack of a small problems — how do you expect one page number to make sense for two completely unrelated queries? It's like reading two different books at the same time.

You seem to be splitting `post` into virtual "kinds" of post via custom field. Why that have its uses, it wouldn't be my first take on this issue.

Without *knowing* more details my first take would be to introduce Custom Post Type for anything other than native `post` and make use of its own archive for navigation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and informative supply!  That link you've provided is really helpful too.

I think what I'll do is strip out the arguments leave it as a standard wordpress blog loop and come up with another solution for applying the post selectors: article and webinar.